# VBScript получение текста из XMLnode

Tags: xml, vbscript

Имеется вот такой скрипт vbs:

```
set xml=CreateObject("Msxml.DOMDocument")
success=xml.load("data1.xml")
set root=xml.documentElement
set nodes=root.SelectNodes("Группа")
WScript.Echo(nodes(0).text)
```

и xml такого вида:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<Успеваемость>
    <Группа>ИКС-007
        <Студент>
            <ФИО>Иванов</ФИО><Зачетка>12345</Зачетка>
                <Предмет>Информатика
                    <Семестр>1<Оценка>
                        <Зачет>зачтено</Зачет>
                        <Экзамен>5</Экзамен>
                    </Оценка></Семестр></Предмет>
                <Предмет>Физика
                    <Семестр>2<Оценка>
                        <Зачет>зачтено</Зачет>
                        <РГР>4</РГР>
                        <Экзамен>3</Экзамен>
                    </Оценка></Семестр></Предмет>
        </Студент>
    </Группа>
</Успеваемость>
```

Необходимо, чтобы код выводил только название группы (ИКС-007), но вместо этого выводится все дерево. В чем косяк?

Comment: надо обращаться так: nodes(0).childNodes(0).text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У 0-й ноды, надо обратиться к коллекции childNodes и у неё взять 0-й элемент

```
nodes(0).childNodes(0).text
```

Comment: Спасибо! помогло